# How do I add a Python list to a Django HTTP response

Tags: python, django, httpresponse

I am trying to run Python code over a Django site and the goal is that the return list from the Python function will be shown at the response site:

In my views.py:

```
def home(request):

form = SignUpForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    save_it= form.save(commit=False)
    save_it.save()
    messages.success(request,"Working, please wait........")
    answer = crawler("http://www.walla.co.il",5,5)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/done/')

return render_to_response("signup.html",locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
def done(request):
return render_to_response("done.html",locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

My function is defined in craw.py

---

I understand what you wrote down and it helped, but how do I redirect? And I have a global variable, `contex`:

```
    contex = { 'list_var' : list_var }
    #context = { 'list_var' : list_var }
    #return render(request, 'done.html', context)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/done/')

    #return HttpResponseRedirect('/done/')

return render_to_response("signup.html",locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def done(request):
    global contex
    return render_to_response("done.html",locals(),contex)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question right, you need to send the list to the template you want to load and iterate through it there.

I personally use the render shortcut shown [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/) .

For example:

```
 list_var = [1,2,3]
 context = { 'list_var' : list_var }
 return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

and then in the template iterate through the data sent like this:

```
{% for x in list_var %}
      {{ x }}
{% endfor %}
```

Hope this helps, cheers :)

Comment: how do i use it with redirect to new site?
        contex = { 'list_var' : list_var }
        #context = { 'list_var' : list_var }
        #return render(request, 'done.html', context)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/done/')
        #return HttpResponseRedirect('/done/')
    return render_to_response("signup.html",locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def done(request):
    global contex
    return render_to_response("done.html",locals(),contex)

Comment: i wrote it up more clean

Comment: I don't understand why not send the list on the same path you are trying to reach?